# Confluence - Atlassian:: Two own-developed-plugins block each other

Tags: confluence, xwork

I have developed two plugins for Confluence.
When I install only one of them, everything works as expected. But when both are installed and I want to visit the Configuration-URL for one of them, there comes the error "Page not found".

Here are the 2 atlassin-plugin.xml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<atlassian-plugin key="${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}" name="${project.name}" plugins-version="2">
  <plugin-info>
    <description>${project.description}</description>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <vendor name="${project.organization.name}" url="${project.organization.url}"/>
    <param name="plugin-icon">images/pluginIcon.png</param>
    <param name="plugin-logo">images/pluginLogo.png</param>
    <param name="configure.url">/admin/plugins/report/configuration.action</param>
  </plugin-info>

  <resource type="i18n" name="i18n" location="/i18n/report"/>


  <web-resource key="report-page-resources" name="Report page Web Resources">
    <resource type="download" name="report.js" location="js/report.js"/>
    <resource type="download" name="melden.css" location="css/melden.css"/>
    <resource type="download" name="load_cats.gif" location="images/load_cats.gif"/>
    <dependency>confluence.web.resources:ajs</dependency>
    <context>atl.general</context>
  </web-resource>

  <web-item key="report-button" name="Report Button" section="system.content.action/marker" weight="40">
    <label key="de.essendi.confluence.report.label"/>
    <styleClass>reportButton</styleClass>
    <link>/</link>
  </web-item>
  <xwork name="Report Admin Configuration" key="melden-admin-configuration-action">
    <package name="configuration" extends="default" namespace="/admin/plugins/report">
      <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
      <action name="configuration" class="de.essendi.confluence.report.admin.action.ConfigureActionReport">
        <result name="success" type="velocity">/templates/melden-configurationaction.vm</result>
      </action>
      <action name="submit" class="de.essendi.confluence.report.admin.action.SubmitActionReport">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">/admin/plugins/report/configuration.action</result>
      </action>
    </package>
  </xwork>
  <rest key="report-rest" path="/report" version="1.0">
    <description>Provides the Report REST Api.</description>
    <package>de.essendi.confluence.report.rest</package>
  </rest>
  <component key="report-settings-manager" class="de.essendi.confluence.report.admin.DefaultReportSettingsManager" interface="de.essendi.confluence.report.admin.ReportSettingsManager"/>
  <!-- import from the product container -->
  <component-import key="applicationProperties" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.ApplicationProperties"/>

  <component key="report-mail-service-impl" class="de.essendi.confluence.report.email.MailServiceImpl" name="Mail Service Impl" i18n-name-key="mail-service-impl.name">
    <description key="mail-service-impl.description">The Mail Service Impl Plugin</description>
    <interface>de.essendi.confluence.report.email.MailService</interface>
  </component>

 <component-import key="i18nResolver" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.message.I18nResolver"/>
  <component-import key="task-manager" interface="com.atlassian.core.task.MultiQueueTaskManager" filter=""/>
</atlassian-plugin>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<atlassian-plugin key="${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}" name="${project.name}" plugins-version="2">
  <plugin-info>
    <description>${project.description}</description>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <vendor name="${project.organization.name}" url="${project.organization.url}"/>
    <param name="plugin-icon">images/pluginIcon.png</param>
    <param name="plugin-logo">images/pluginLogo.png</param>
    <param name="configure.url">/admin/plugins/groupfilter/configuration.action</param>
  </plugin-info>
  <!-- add our i18n resource -->
  <resource type="i18n" name="i18n" location="groupFilter"/>
  <!-- add our web resources -->
  <web-resource key="groupFilter-resources" name="groupFilter Web Resources">
    <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>
    <resource type="download" name="groupFilter.css" location="/css/groupFilter.css"/>
    <resource type="download" name="groupFilter.js" location="/js/groupFilter.js"/>
    <resource type="download" name="images/" location="/images"/>
    <context>groupFilter</context>
  </web-resource>

  <xwork name="Groupfilter Admin Configuration" key="groupfilter-admin-configuration-action">
    <package name="configuration" extends="default" namespace="/admin/plugins/groupfilter">
      <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
      <action name="configuration" class="de.essendi.confluence.groupFilter.admin.action.ConfigurationAction">
        <result name="success" type="velocity">/templates/groupfilter-configurationaction.vm</result>
      </action>
      <action name="submit" class="de.essendi.confluence.groupFilter.admin.action.SubmitAction">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">/admin/plugins/groupfilter/configuration.action</result>
      </action>
    </package>
  </xwork>

   <component name="LDAP Sync Listener" class="de.essendi.confluence.groupFilter.SyncEvent" key="groupfilter-syncevent-listener"/>
  <!-- import from the product container -->
  <component-import key="applicationProperties" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.ApplicationProperties"/>
  <component key="group-filter-manger-impl" class="de.essendi.confluence.groupFilter.admin.GroupFilterMangerImpl" name="Group Filter Manger Impl" i18n-name-key="group-filter-manger-impl.name">
    <description key="group-filter-manger-impl.description">The Group Filter Manger Impl Plugin</description>
    <interface>de.essendi.confluence.groupFilter.admin.GroupFilterManager</interface>
  </component>
</atlassian-plugin>
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: Try uninstalling both plugins, then reinstalling both one after the other. What errors do you see in the log? If none, what errors do you see in the log when you try to access each configuration URL? (And are both URLs broken, or just one of them?) Lastly, are you using different groupIds and artifactIds in your pom.xml for each individual plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your package names inside the xwork elements are unique. In your example both packages are called **name="configuration"**. This leads to only the last enabled package being active.

Answer (score 0):

key="${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}" indicates that the plugin identifier is taken from maven's pom.xml. Are you sure that the groupId and/or the artifactId are different in pom.xml ?

Also, go to the add-on list and check if both plugins are really listed there and what their keys are.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The plugins themself work as expected. Only the xWork-Modules don't work in combination